# storing session in redis server from ASP.net while redirecting to some other page using Response.redirect it is throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis

[image: Serialization and Deserialization Error from redis]

I have Serialize all class from which I am adding object parameter in session and all session value are storing except which is not in aspx.cs page. after that Redirecting aspx page to some other page but it is throwing error when I have done  throwOnError="false" in web.config page  it is not throwing error but its session value is not coming and afterword it is not storing any session value in to the application.

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: It looks like you are trying to serialize your HttpRequest which is not serializable (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx). Please add the code of the class you serialize and the serialization-call so we can find out why the request is in there...

Answer (score 0):

The official answer from Microsoft:

> Unfortunately HttpWebRequest dropped
>   support for serialization after .NET 1.1. See
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.httpwebrequest(v=VS.100).aspx
>   We’ll see if we can get that attribute removed to avoid this confusion
>   in the future.

They changed the documentation to include the [ObsoleteAttribute] attribute.